# List Comprehension multi line string to 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, list-comprehension

I'm experiencing issues in solving a problem. I need to transform the following string

```
meciuri = """Romania 4 - 0 Franta
Italia 2 - 1 Rusia
Franta 3 - 0 Italia
Rusia 2 - 2 Romania
Romania 1 - 0 Italia
Franta 2 - 1 Rusia"""
```

into a 2d array which would look like this

```
meciuri_2darray = [['Romania', '4', '-', '0' ,'Franta'],
['Italia' ,'2' ,'-', '1', 'Rusia'], 
['Franta' ,'3' ,'-' ,'0', 'Italia'], 
['Rusia', '2', '-', '2', 'Romania'],
['Romania', '1' ,'-' ,'0' ,'Italia'],
['Franta' ,'2' ,'-' ,'1' ,'Rusia']]
```

I have tried different variations but I'm really newbie with 2d arrays and list comprehensions. This is what I managed to get so far but the result doesn't satisfy me at all

```
meciuri_2darray = [[i for i in meciuri.split('\n')] for line in meciuri]
```

Output

```
[['R'], ['o'], ['m'], ['a'], ['n'], ['i'], ['a'], [' '], ['4'], [' '], ['-'], [' '], ['0'], [' '], ['F'], ['r'], ['a'], ['n'], ['t'], ['a'], ['', ''], ['I'], ['t'], ['a'], ['l'], ['i'], ['a'], [' '], ['2'], [' '], ['-'], [' '], ['1'], [' '], ['R'], ['u'], ['s'], ['i'], ['a'], ['', ''], ['F'], ['r'], ['a'], ['n'], ['t'],
['a'], [' '], ['3'], [' '], ['-'], [' '], ['0'], [' '], ['I'], ['t'], ['a'], ['l'], ['i'], ['a'], ['', ''], ['R'], ['u'], ['s'], ['i'], ['a'], [' '], ['2'], [' '], ['-'], [' '], ['2'], [' '], ['R'], ['o'], ['m'], ['a'], ['n'], ['i'], ['a'], ['', ''], ['R'], ['o'], ['m'], ['a'], ['n'], ['i'], ['a'], [' '], ['1'], [' '], ['-'], [' '], ['0'], [' '], ['I'], ['t'], ['a'], ['l'], ['i'], ['a'], ['', ''], ['F'], ['r'], ['a'], ['n'], ['t'], ['a'], [' '], ['2'], [' '], ['-'], [' '], ['1'], [' '], ['R'], ['u'], ['s'], ['i'], ['a']]
```

Comment: `[m.split() for m in meciuri.split('\n')]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a non-nested list comprehension:

```
meciuri_2darray = [i.split() for i in meciuri.split('\n')]

# [['Romania', '4', '-', '0', 'Franta'],
#  ['Italia', '2', '-', '1', 'Rusia'],
#  ['Franta', '3', '-', '0', 'Italia'],
#  ['Rusia', '2', '-', '2', 'Romania'],
#  ['Romania', '1', '-', '0', 'Italia'],
#  ['Franta', '2', '-', '1', 'Rusia']]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
meciuri = """Romania 4 - 0 Franta
Italia 2 - 1 Rusia
Franta 3 - 0 Italia
Rusia 2 - 2 Romania
Romania 1 - 0 Italia
Franta 2 - 1 Rusia"""
l=meciuri.split(os.linesep)
print([x.split(" ") for x in l])
```